# Getting java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException : String index out of range: (not able to figure it out)

Tags: java, inputstream, java.util.scanner

I have a piece of code -

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform;

public class RAF {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

          File file = new File("test.txt");
          Scanner scanner;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\n");
            String line = scanner.next();
              String newLine = line.substring(0, 252) + "<input type=\"button\" value = \"abhishek\" />" + line.substring(252);
              FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
              writer.write(newLine);
              writer.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

and the test.txt file is -

```
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD
> HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
> "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
> <html> <head> <meta
> http-equiv="Content-Type"
> content="text/html;
> charset=ISO-8859-1"> <title>Insert
> title here</title> </head> <body>
> 
> <form><input></form> </body> </html>
```

The total length of test.txt is 285 and I want to add the content at 252 location so that the output will be -

```
> "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
> <html> <head> <meta
> http-equiv="Content-Type"
> content="text/html;
> charset=ISO-8859-1"> <title>Insert
> title here</title> </head> <body>
> 
> <form>**<input type="button" value =
> "abhishek"/>**<input></form> </body>
> </html>
```

But I am getting exception -
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 252
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at com.lg.palette.elementEditFactory.RAF.main(RAF.java:25)

What is the problem with the code
My main objective is to get the content as shown in the 2nd test.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only reading the first *line* of the file... which isn't 252 characters long. It looks like you really want to read the whole file in and then modify it.

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) has some useful methods in `Files` to read an entire file in one go.

(In general this feels like a pretty fragile approach though... how confident are you that the split point will always be 252 characters into the HTML?)

Comment: 252 is just a random point I mentioned, Actually I am using an algorithm to fetch that point where the code need to be placed. Its just a sample for my issue....Is Guava is the only way to do, Can't I use RandomAccessFile.. I tried but I think I am making some mistake with Random...

Comment: @Abhishek: You can read the whole file any way you like - Guava just makes it easy. I don't think you really want RandomAccessFile, if you're trying to read the whole file... you can just use FileInputStream and an InputStreamReader.

Comment: I want to read the file and in the specific point I want to write my content.. when I am trying sometime I am loosing other contents, so not able to figure it out. my Actual destination is to write the content in the mid(random point) of the file

Comment: @Abhishek: Yes, you can't just write in the middle of the file, or you'll overwrite other data. One option is to just copy the first n bytes into a new file, then write the new data, then copy the rest of the original file. Note that a number of bytes isn't necessarily the same as a number of characters...